# how to establish database connection in kohana mvc framework

Tags: phpmyadmin, kohana-orm, kohana-3.3, kohana-auth

I am trying to create a login/Signup page using Auth/ORM module of kohana. i have succesfully installed the MySQLi module and added a line in the bootstrap.php file. Now when I try to create an account with all the details entered i get an error stating ErrorException [ Notice ]: Trying to get property of non-object in line no. 67 of MySQLi.php file. I am using xampp/phpmyAdmin.

the error is in line: ':code' => $this->_connection->connect_errno,

class Kohana_Database_MySQLi extends Database {

```
// Database in use by each connection
protected static $_current_databases = array();

// Use SET NAMES to set the character set
protected static $_set_names;

// Identifier for this connection within the PHP driver
protected $_connection_id;

// MySQL uses a backtick for identifiers
protected $_identifier = '`';

public function connect()
{
    if ($this->_connection)
        return;

    if (Database_MySQLi::$_set_names === NULL)
    {
        // Determine if we can use mysqli_set_charset(), which is only
        // available on PHP 5.2.3+ when compiled against MySQL 5.0+
        Database_MySQLi::$_set_names = ! function_exists('mysqli_set_charset');
    }

    // Extract the connection parameters, adding required variabels
    extract($this->_config['connection'] + array(
        'database'   => 'kohana',
        'hostname'   => 'localhost',
        'port'       => ini_get("mysqli.default_port"),
        'socket'     => ini_get("mysqli.default_socket"),
        'username'   => FALSE,
        'password'   => FALSE,
        'persistent' => FALSE,
    ));

    // Prevent this information from showing up in traces
    //unset($this->_config['connection']['username'], $this->_config['connection']['password']);

    try
    {
        if ($persistent)
        {
            // Create a persistent connection
            $this->_connection = new MySQLi('p:'.$hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port, $socket);
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a connection and force it to be a new link
            $this->_connection = new MySQLi($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port, $socket);
        }
    }
    catch (ErrorException $e)
    {
        throw new Database_Exception('[:code] :error', array(
                **':code' => $this->_connection->connect_errno,**
                ':error' => $this->_connection->connect_error,
            ), $this->_connection->connect_errno);

        // No connection exists
        $this->_connection = NULL;
    }

    // \xFF is a better delimiter, but the PHP driver uses underscore
    $this->_connection_id = sha1($hostname.'_'.$username.'_'.$password);

    $this->_select_db($database);

    if ( ! empty($this->_config['charset']))
    {
        // Set the character set
        $this->set_charset($this->_config['charset']);
    }
}

/**
 * Select the database
 *
 * @param   string  Database
 * @return  void
 */
protected function _select_db($database)
{
    if ( ! $this->_connection->select_db($database))
    {
        // Unable to select database
        throw new Database_Exception('[:code] :error', array(
            ':code' => $this->_connection->errno,
            ':error' => $this->_connection->error,
        ), $this->_connection->errno);
    }

    Database_MySQLi::$_current_databases[$this->_connection_id] = $database;
}

public function disconnect()
{
    try
    {
        // Database is assumed disconnected
        $status = TRUE;

        if ($this->_connection instanceof mysqli)
        {
            if ($status = $this->_connection->close())
            {
                // Clear the connection
                $this->_connection = NULL;
            }
        }

        parent::disconnect();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // Database is probably not disconnected
        $status = ! ($this->_connection instanceof mysqli);
    }

    return $status;
}

public function set_charset($charset)
{
    // Make sure the database is connected
    $this->_connection or $this->connect();

    if (Database_MySQLi::$_set_names === TRUE)
    {
        // PHP is compiled against MySQL 4.x
        $status = (bool) $this->_connection->query('SET NAMES '.$this->quote($charset));
    }
    else
    {
        // PHP is compiled against MySQL 5.x
        $status = $this->_connection->set_charset($charset);
    }

    if ($status === FALSE)
    {
        throw new Database_Exception('[:code] :error', array(
            ':code' => $this->_connection->errno,
            ':error' => $this->_connection->error,
        ), $this->_connection->errno);
    }
}

public function query($type, $sql, $as_object = FALSE, array $params = NULL)
{
    // Make sure the database is connected
    $this->_connection or $this->connect();

    if ( ! empty($this->_config['profiling']))
    {
        // Benchmark this query for the current instance
        $benchmark = Profiler::start("Database ({$this->_instance})", $sql);
    }

    if ( ! empty($this->_config['connection']['persistent']) AND $this->_config['connection']['database'] !== Database_MySQLi::$_current_databases[$this->_connection_id])
    {
        // Select database on persistent connections
        $this->_select_db($this->_config['connection']['database']);
    }

    // Execute the query
    if (($result = $this->_connection->query($sql)) === FALSE)
    {
        if (isset($benchmark))
        {
            // This benchmark is worthless
            Profiler::delete($benchmark);
        }

        throw new Database_Exception('[:code] :error ( :query )', array(
            ':code' => $this->_connection->errno,
            ':error' => $this->_connection->error,
            ':query' => $sql,
        ), $this->_connection->errno);
    }

    if (isset($benchmark))
    {
        Profiler::stop($benchmark);
    }

    // Set the last query
    $this->last_query = $sql;

    if ($type === Database::SELECT)
    {
        // Return an iterator of results
        return new Database_MySQLi_Result($result, $sql, $as_object, $params);
    }
    elseif ($type === Database::INSERT)
    {
        // Return a list of insert id and rows created
        return array(
            $this->_connection->insert_id,
            $this->_connection->affected_rows,
        );
    }
    else
    {
        // Return the number of rows affected
        return $this->_connection->affected_rows;
    }
}

public function datatype($type)
{
    static $types = array
    (
        'blob'                      => array('type' => 'string', 'binary' => TRUE, 'character_maximum_length' => '65535'),
        'bool'                      => array('type' => 'bool'),
        'bigint unsigned'           => array('type' => 'int', 'min' => '0', 'max' => '18446744073709551615'),
        'datetime'                  => array('type' => 'string'),
        'decimal unsigned'          => array('type' => 'float', 'exact' => TRUE, 'min' => '0'),
        'double'                    => array('type' => 'float'),
        'double precision unsigned' => array('type' => 'float', 'min' => '0'),
        'double unsigned'           => array('type' => 'float', 'min' => '0'),
        'enum'                      => array('type' => 'string'),
        'fixed'                     => array('type' => 'float', 'exact' => TRUE),
        'fixed unsigned'            => array('type' => 'float', 'exact' => TRUE, 'min' => '0'),
        'float unsigned'            => array('type' => 'float', 'min' => '0'),
        'int unsigned'              => array('type' => 'int', 'min' => '0', 'max' => '4294967295'),
        'integer unsigned'          => array('type' => 'int', 'min' => '0', 'max' => '4294967295'),
        'longblob'                  => array('type' => 'string', 'binary' => TRUE, 'character_maximum_length' => '4294967295'),
        'longtext'                  => array('type' => 'string', 'character_maximum_length' => '4294967295'),
        'mediumblob'                => array('type' => 'string', 'binary' => TRUE, 'character_maximum_length' => '16777215'),
        'mediumint'                 => array('type' => 'int', 'min' => '-8388608', 'max' => '8388607'),
        'mediumint unsigned'        => array('type' => 'int', 'min' => '0', 'max' => '16777215'),
        'mediumtext'                => array('type' => 'string', 'character_maximum_length' => '16777215'),
        'national varchar'          => array('type' => 'string'),
        'numeric unsigned'          => array('type' => 'float', 'exact' => TRUE, 'min' => '0'),
        'nvarchar'                  => array('type' => 'string'),
        'point'                     => array('type' => 'string', 'binary' => TRUE),
        'real unsigned'             => array('type' => 'float', 'min' => '0'),
        'set'                       => array('type' => 'string'),
        'smallint unsigned'         => array('type' => 'int', 'min' => '0', 'max' => '65535'),
        'text'                      => array('type' => 'string', 'character_maximum_length' => '65535'),
        'tinyblob'                  => array('type' => 'string', 'binary' => TRUE, 'character_maximum_length' => '255'),
        'tinyint'                   => array('type' => 'int', 'min' => '-128', 'max' => '127'),
        'tinyint unsigned'          => array('type' => 'int', 'min' => '0', 'max' => '255'),
        'tinytext'                  => array('type' => 'string', 'character_maximum_length' => '255'),
        'year'                      => array('type' => 'string'),
    );

    $type = str_replace(' zerofill', '', $type);

    if (isset($types[$type]))
        return $types[$type];

    return parent::datatype($type);
}

/**
 * Start a SQL transaction
 *
 * @link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html
 *
 * @param string Isolation level
 * @return boolean
 */
public function begin($mode = NULL)
{
    // Make sure the database is connected
    $this->_connection or $this->connect();

    if ($mode AND ! $this->_connection->query("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL $mode"))
    {
        throw new Database_Exception(':error', array(':error' => $this->_connection->error),
                                     $this->_connection->errno);
    }

    return (bool) $this->_connection->query('START TRANSACTION');
}

/**
 * Commit a SQL transaction
 *
 * @param string Isolation level
 * @return boolean
 */
public function commit()
{
    // Make sure the database is connected
    $this->_connection or $this->connect();

    return (bool) $this->_connection->query('COMMIT');
}

/**
 * Rollback a SQL transaction
 *
 * @param string Isolation level
 * @return boolean
 */
public function rollback()
{
    // Make sure the database is connected
    $this->_connection or $this->connect();

    return (bool) $this->_connection->query('ROLLBACK');
}

public function list_tables($like = NULL)
{
    if (is_string($like))
    {
        // Search for table names
        $result = $this->query(Database::SELECT, 'SHOW TABLES LIKE '.$this->quote($like), FALSE);
    }
    else
    {
        // Find all table names
        $result = $this->query(Database::SELECT, 'SHOW TABLES', FALSE);
    }

    $tables = array();
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        $tables[] = reset($row);
    }

    return $tables;
}

public function list_columns($table, $like = NULL, $add_prefix = TRUE)
{
    // Quote the table name
    $table = ($add_prefix === TRUE) ? $this->quote_table($table) : $table;

    if (is_string($like))
    {
        // Search for column names
        $result = $this->query(Database::SELECT, 'SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM '.$table.' LIKE '.$this->quote($like), FALSE);
    }
    else
    {
        // Find all column names
        $result = $this->query(Database::SELECT, 'SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM '.$table, FALSE);
    }

    $count = 0;
    $columns = array();
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        list($type, $length) = $this->_parse_type($row['Type']);

        $column = $this->datatype($type);

        $column['column_name']      = $row['Field'];
        $column['column_default']   = $row['Default'];
        $column['data_type']        = $type;
        $column['is_nullable']      = ($row['Null'] == 'YES');
        $column['ordinal_position'] = ++$count;

        switch ($column['type'])
        {
            case 'float':
                if (isset($length))
                {
                    list($column['numeric_precision'], $column['numeric_scale']) = explode(',', $length);
                }
            break;
            case 'int':
                if (isset($length))
                {
                    // MySQL attribute
                    $column['display'] = $length;
                }
            break;
            case 'string':
                switch ($column['data_type'])
                {
                    case 'binary':
                    case 'varbinary':
                        $column['character_maximum_length'] = $length;
                    break;
                    case 'char':
                    case 'varchar':
                        $column['character_maximum_length'] = $length;
                    case 'text':
                    case 'tinytext':
                    case 'mediumtext':
                    case 'longtext':
                        $column['collation_name'] = $row['Collation'];
                    break;
                    case 'enum':
                    case 'set':
                        $column['collation_name'] = $row['Collation'];
                        $column['options'] = explode('\',\'', substr($length, 1, -1));
                    break;
                }
            break;
        }

        // MySQL attributes
        $column['comment']      = $row['Comment'];
        $column['extra']        = $row['Extra'];
        $column['key']          = $row['Key'];
        $column['privileges']   = $row['Privileges'];

        $columns[$row['Field']] = $column;
    }

    return $columns;
}

public function escape($value)
{
    // Make sure the database is connected
    $this->_connection or $this->connect();

    if (($value = $this->_connection->real_escape_string((string) $value)) === FALSE)
    {
        throw new Database_Exception('[:code] :error', array(
            ':code' => $this->_connection->errno,
            ':error' => $this->_connection->error,
        ), $this->_connection->errno);
    }

    // SQL standard is to use single-quotes for all values
    return "'$value'";
}
```

} // End Database_MySQLi

Answer (score 0):

There is a `database.php`, You can find it in `/modules/database/config`

There you can fill in your database credentials.